# PHP replace preceding substrings of some other substring

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

Let's say I have this string:

```
$myString = 'aaa = b AND cc = dd OR e = ff_%_g AND hh = iii AND j = k_%_lll ...'
```

I want to check if the substring `'_%_'` is present, and in that case, I want to replace the previous (and only the previous) `'='` by a `'LIKE'`.

Namely, I want this:

```
$myString = 'aaa = b AND cc = dd OR e LIKE ff_%_g AND hh = iii AND j LIKE k_%_lll ...'
```

I know how to replace all the `'='` using `strpos()` and `substr_replace()`, but I need to replace only those that precede a `'_%_'`

Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$myString = preg_replace("/=([^=]*_%_[^ ]*)/", "LIKE $1", $myString);
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Don't know why, but I think I'll never get along well with regexps :)

Comment: @hek2mgl, can you explain your edit? Shouldn't it work fine without that?

Comment: @MikO No, without the `[^ ]*` it would make `foo_%_` out of `foo_%_bar`. The answer was  basically good, so I decided to edit this.